# Counting rows using data across two tables in a mySQL database

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to COUNT() daily new visitors but the data I need is split across two tables in my database.

---

**mySQL table structure**

I have two tables, the first table looks like this - the table registers new visitors:

```
-- uniqueVisitors - as new visitors are seen they are added to this table

+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uniqueVisitorID    | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| uuID               | varchar(36) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| websitePrivateHash | varchar(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| dateFirstSeen      | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| dateLastSeen       | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My second table looks like this - it registers a visitors page views each day:

```
-- visitorPageViews - visitors daily page views are tracked here. 

+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| visitorPageViewID  | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| websitePrivateHash | varchar(16) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uuID               | varchar(36) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date               | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pageViews          | int         | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

---

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to get the visitor count from `visitorPageViews` where `dateFirstSeen` on `uniqueVisitors` is not the same date.

I've tried working with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(visitorPageViews.uuID) AS count 
FROM uniqueVisitors, visitorPageViews 
WHERE uniqueVisitors.websitePrivateHash = visitorPageViews.websitePrivateHash 
AND visitorPageViews.websitePrivateHash = 'r2d2****c3po****' 
AND visitorPageViews.date = '2023-12-28' 
AND uniqueVisitors.dateFirstSeen != '2023-12-28';
```

But it returns a number in the millions which sadly isn't a true reflection of new visitors.

I could make changes to the data structure if there is a better way to track this data, but I'd rather not.

Comment: An option I considered was changing the `dateLastSeen` to `datesSeen` and appending each date to the field, but that would mean doing additional checks & string manipulation to use the data and generally didn't seem very clean.

Comment: If you have more details, click the Edit button and add them to the question, don't write them in comments.

Comment: Maybe you meant `COUNT(DISTINCT visitorPageViews.uuID)`?

Comment: Aside: Learn to use ANSI JOIN, not archaic comma syntax to join tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly we can't replicate the same conditions, but given the objective I would approach the query as below. Note I have used a join condition (instead of the where clause) to ensure page views tare after the `dateFirstSeen`:

```
SELECT
      COUNT(p.uuID) AS count_all
    , COUNT(DISTINCT p.uuID) AS count_distinct
FROM visitorPageViews p
INNER JOIN uniqueVisitors v ON p.websitePrivateHash = v.websitePrivateHash
    AND v.dateFirstSeen < p.DATE
WHERE p.websitePrivateHash = 'r2d2****c3po****'
```

nb: Unsure if you need `count(distinct o.uuID)` or not:

| count_all | count_distinct |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rVuEGhiW)